# SoundManager plugin pause it and remember with a cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, soundmanager2

I've found a snippet on the internet that uses soundmanager, it allows loading a page and keeping the background music at the same position it was before.
It has a buton to play/pause it, with a cookie to remember the music's and button's state.
The button works fine when i click it, it plays or pauses the music and it changes its icon (from > to || or from || to >). If i pause the music and then reload the page, the music starts playing again and the button's icon stays the same.

If you don't understand my dirty description of the problem, check it:
http://verypgm.net16.net/portfolio/

And there's the script:

```
var son;
soundManager.onload = function() {
  var bouton_muet = document.getElementById('muet');
  var cookie_muet = getCookie('SM2muet');
  if(cookie_muet == "") { cookie_muet = "unmuted"; }
    son = soundManager.createSound(
    {
        id : "son",
        url : "msc/HammockTheHouseWhereWeGrewUp.mp3",
        volume: "30",
    onload : function() {
      if(cookie_muet == "muted") {
        bouton_muet.src = "scr/m/p2.png";
        son.pause();
      }else{
        bouton_muet.src = "scr/m/p1.png";
}
      var position = getCookie('SM2position');
      if(position=="") { position = 0; }
      son.setPosition(position);
     son.play();
    },
    onfinish : function() {
      son.setPosition(0);
    },
    autoLoad : true
    });
  bouton_muet.onclick = function() {
    if(son.paused) {
      son.play();
      this.src = "scr/m/p1.png";
    } else {
      son.pause();
      this.src = "scr/m/p2.png";
    }
  };
};


window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  setCookie('SM2position',son.position,1);
  setCookie('SM2muet',(son.paused?'muted':'unmuted'),1);
};

function setCookie(c_name, value, expiredays) {
  var exdate=new Date();
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
  document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value)+
  ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toGMTString());
}
function getCookie(c_name) {
  if (document.cookie.length>0) {
    c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    if (c_start!=-1) { 
      c_start=c_start + c_name.length+1; 
      c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start);
      if (c_end==-1) c_end=document.cookie.length;
      return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
    } 
  }
  return "";
}
```

It's really important to me because the music really goes with my photographies, i want visitors to listen what inspires me
So thanks for reading/heping me!

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed save the name of the song playing (if you have multiple songs) and when loading the webpage use something like this:

```
s = soundManager.getSoundById(nameOfSong);
s.setPosition(offsetInSeconds);
s.play();
```

Not really rocketscience...